# .on('connection') for an express server

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to create a basic web server with express for node.js. I know that the http module has a `.on('connection',function(client){})` method that is called whenever a client connects. Is there a similar method for express?

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is quite old, but I had the same one and was able to figure out the answer, so I thought I would post it here for anyone else who may be looking.

According to the [Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen) with Express 4.x, the `listen` method returns an `http.Server` object, so all methods that can be used on `http.Server.listen` are also available on the Express `listen` method.

With this in mind, the answer to your question is yes, and below is an example of how you can achieve it in Express 4.x.

```
const app = express();

app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
  // Add your code for this route here
});

const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});

server.on('connection', function (client) {
  // Do your thang here
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily add a route that will be matched against "everything", that is:

```
app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("received request: " + req.originalUrl);
  next();
});
```

This is simply a middleware that, once a client executes any rest api to your server, will log the url and call `next()` to continue to the next matching route

Comment: This is not called when a client connects server (= TCP stream established). Middleware fires when a client **ends a request**.